# How to make Google extension recognized by website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google Extension that needs to regularly pole a page on a website.

The thing is the page is only available after log-in. So I logged in to the site through normal means then ran the extension. However, it appears the site is not recognizing the request from my extension as coming from the browser that is already logged in.

Is there a way to make requests with an extension that will be seen as being made by a logged in user?

The only code I have that might be relevant is the jQuery call I am using:

```
jQuery.get( vote_page, function( data ) {
  page = data;
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Is this code running under the background page context or as an executed DOM script?

Comment: Ah..I think I know where this might be going; it is running on a background page.

Comment: I think you may have your answer then :). Your script is not running under the context you are expecting it to.

Comment: Hm. If the authentication is cookie-based, then it should work. What if you open the same page you're querying in a new tab?

Comment: Thanks Xan. Yeah, I'm still trying to figure out why the cookies don't kick in. I know if I open another browser window, I am recognized by the website. So I am not 100% clear why a background page would not get the same recognition.